# Is it possible to transmit a video over a 433 MHz RF module?

Tags: wireless, radio, transmitter, 433mhz, video-transmitter

Is it possible in any case to transmit a video over a [433 MHz RF module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DKC2EY4)?

Comment: Depends on what "video" is. With a datarate of say 10kBit/s you can transmit 10 images a 1000Bit per second. Using boolean black/white encoding this gives you 32x32Pixel image resolution. Of course, every bit is transmitted here without any extra overhead and compression. Lets say you have 10% protocoll overhead and can run a compression of 25%: This would give you 12kPixels/Second. If you are good with 4fps (Surveilance or what not) this gives you 54x54 Pixels - sufficient for some applications which require a long range and cheap wireless video feed.

But fancy 1080p? Nope - not at all.

Comment: Do you mean a live video stream or some mp4 file?

Comment: @Mohamed perhaps you should define what 'video' means to you in your application.  Take a look at the help https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/asking on how to improve your question. A poorly defined open question can only provide low quality answers as answers can only be in general terms.  Without a better question the answer to your question is all of YES or No or Maybe.  I suggest you rephrase and expand on your question before somebody closes it as not specific or too broad.

Comment: In practice, the regulations of the band would make it difficult since you would be restricted to 1mW ERP for broadband transfers. If range is not a problem then at least in theory you can use a multi-channel technology of some ~1MHz bandwidth and high baudrate and still remain compliant with band regulations as well as the ETSI standards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The data rate needed for video is way higher than these modules can provide.

What data rate can they provide? They don't directly tell you, and these things don't have proper datasheets (as with many Chinese knockoff Arduino accessories), but if I Google it and find [some random datasheet for a similar module](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/22574/DS337_2.pdf) it specifies a max modulation rate of 10 kHz, so 10k bits per second is your maximum. (You're not doing some fancy encoding to squeeze out more than one bit per Hz; even if you could, you still wouldn't have enough bits)

As a point of comparison, [YouTube recommends](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en#zippy=%2Cvideo-codec-h%2Cbitrate) using 1Mbps for 360p video at 30fps without HDR. That is 100 times greater, and that is with complicated compression algorithms (to squish the same video into less bits) that are too heavy to run on a microcontroller.

Comment: To answer 'no' you make an assumpton about what the op means by 'video' and what is acceptable in their case.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, yes. But not at a frame rate, latency or quality that would be considered conventional (or acceptable) at modern television, steaming video or CCTV standards.

There are two methods, both of which are too complicated for a simple Q&A so I've linked some references.

- Slow scan analog broadcast TV, ([more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-scan_television)) often used by radio ammatures and older space probes.
- Highly compressed digital video ([more info](https://ipvm.com/reports/test-ip-video-over-super-low-bandwidth)) the digital equivalent of the above.

Theoretically the digital method should be more bandwidth efficent but far more prone to sudden degredation due to noise, whereas the slow scan TV (though fuzzy) will still transmit a recognisable (theough lower quality) picture despite noise.

The analog method is relatilve simple to use with FM or AM transmission and a lower power CPU. Whereas the digital signal requires much more hardware (i.e. a CPU with digital signal processing capability)

Update:
There is a new kid on the block in this field using deep learning, where only the essence of the image is transmitted, that being distilled using artificial intelligence from the original image.  Though I would not consider this a practical solution for anything other than a research project at the current time (2023) and would require massive CPU processing, probably beyond the reach of the individual.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not in real time.
The data rate for typical 433MHz modules is far too slow to support streaming video.

Comment: Not strictly so.  The op fails to define what 'video' means to them. To say "not in real time" you'd have to define what latency is acceptable (i.e. true real time is never possible unless you have accesss to a time machine) and also take into account a number of parameers, e.g. the resolution, pixel colour and brightness quantisation levels, frame rate, content and acceptable compression loss. e.g. I could say I wanted a 10s UHD video but was prepared to define real time as before I get the office timorrow and the video only has 10% moving black and white data.